# Loop trough objects and Selecting the last object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a pictogram, where I loop through objects (with interval method) and each time condition is not met, the code will add .active class. But Now I want to change the last object CSS but it will change one before last.

I have tried .last() function and :last selector but it still selects the one before last.

```
function result3() {
  var place = (person.bmi * 100 / 35);
  var realPlace = parseInt(52953 * place / 100);
  var pictoPlace = parseInt(realPlace / 530);
  var i = 0;

  var timeOut = setInterval(function() {
    if (i == pictoPlace) {
      $(".active:last").css("color", "red");
      clearInterval(timeOut);
    }

    $(".fa-male").eq(i).addClass("active");
    i++

  }, 20)
}
```

This is how it is right now:

[image]

Red one should be last.

Comment: Please share a minimal, verifiable and reproducible example for us to help you better with DOM structure.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8ufcbmrv/2/#&togetherjs=NR0Rqgu4hP

Comment: Just add a `return` statement after the `clearInterval(timeOut);`. The problem is that you're adding the `active` class after you change the last element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is setting the last `.active` red, then adding another `.active` element.

Just move the code that set the class as the first in the `setTimeOut` function:

```
var timeOut = setInterval(function(){
    $(".fa-male").eq(i).addClass("active");
    if (i == pictoPlace){       
        $(".active:last").css( "color", "red" );
        clearInterval(timeOut);
        }
        i++ }
        ,20)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function result3() {
 var place = (person.bmi * 100 / 35);
  var realPlace = parseInt(52953 * place / 100);
  var pictoPlace = parseInt(realPlace / 530);
  var i = 1;

var timeOut = setInterval(function() {
if (i == pictoPlace) {
  $(".active:last").css("color", "red");
  clearInterval(timeOut);
}

$(".fa-male").eq(i).addClass("active");
i++

 }, 20)
}
```